# Cannot find a handle to Mondrian's CacheControl

Tags: cache-control, pentaho, mondrian

I am using Mondrian as my server olap engine.

I have a scenario where some of my dimensions data is changing. When this happens I would like to clear mondrian cache.

I cannot understand how I can get a handle to Mondrian's cache control.

I have a reference to `OlapConnection` object, but I could not find any method that would give a handle to the CacheControl

Any suggestions?

Yosi

Answer (score 3):

The answer given by bhuang3 is right. To access the cache control from an olap4j connection:

```
OlapConnection.unwrap(mondrian.rolap.RolapConnection.class).getCacheControl(null)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can use following APIs to flush the cube's cache

```
mondrian.olap.CacheControl cacheControl = connection.getCacheControl(null);
mondrian.olap.Schema schema = connection.getSchema();
mondrian.olap.Cube cube = schema.lookupCube(cubeName, false);
mondrian.olap.CacheControl.CellRegion cellRegion = cacheControl.createMeasuresRegion(cube);
cacheControl.flush(cellRegion);
```

Or you can flush the schema cache

```
cacheControl.flushSchemaCache();
```

Alternatively, please read [this](http://mondrian.pentaho.com/documentation/cache_control.php) doc to get more details.

Comment: Hi,I have an instance of org.olap4j.OlapConnection and it does not have getCacheControl function. What am I missing??

Comment: Because you are using `org.olap4j.OlapConnection`, but `connection.getCacheControl(null);` is used by `mondrian.olap.Connection`. Or you can use `mondrian.olap4j.MondrianOlap4jConnection`

Comment: That's true. This is because I am using olap4j to query my data. Is there a way to get the CacheControll from the org.olap4j.OlapConnection?